# bxslider not working, images all lined up vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I'm a newbie at Javascript/JQuery
I'm trying to make a bxslider. I'm not being able to work with it, I did all the steps from bxslider website and still can't, been searching and nothing. Instead of working, it's just working as a normal ul, showing all photos vertically.

The libraries

```
 <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
        <script language="javascript" src="css/libraries/jqueryBxslider/jquery.bxslider.js" ></script>
        <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
        <link href="css/libraries/jqueryBxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="javascript">
```

The ul that contains the photos.

```
 <div class="container">
        <ul id="slider">
            <li><img src="css/libraries/images/test1.PNG"/></li>
            <li><img src="css/libraries/images/test2.PNG"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Code at my javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you testing this locally on your PC, or on a server?

Comment: Locally. I'm doing this code at Webstorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to make a  before the  where it contained the JQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

When testing locally, you need to use a full URL (including protocol) in any libraries you link to that use protocol-relative URLs (e.g. `src="//ajax.googleapis.com`).

Change:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise the browser's default behavior is to use the `file://` protocol to search your local file system for jQuery.

Comment: It gives me an error saying that I have no locally stored library for the HTTP link...

Comment: You're getting an error when using the http:// version? Is this an error in your browser or in webstorm?

Comment: Have you tried running the page from a browser? Also I added the webstorm tag to your question since this may be part of your problem.

Comment: It's the same thing. The images stay all lined up.

Comment: And in your browser's console, what errors do you get?

Comment: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: That means that jQuery is still not loaded. Are you sure your page has the full `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js` link to jQuery when you bring it up in a browser?

Comment: It can't get the file... ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Well, I inserted the JQuery code inside a script tag before the <ul> and it worked. Don't know why. Do I need any special thing to put the code in a file that I already created where I have all my javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, make sure your bxslider libraries path `src` on `<script></script>` and `href` on `<link>`is correct.

and then change this line :

```
<link href="css/libraries/jqueryBxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="javascript">
```

to

```
<link href="css/libraries/jqueryBxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

without `type="javascript"` because the type is CSS.

Comment: Removed the "type" and checked the paths. All right but still doing the same thing..